# I'm buying a ticket for another person to travel from Ghana to the US

Tags: payment-cards

Are there any issues if I purchase a round trip air travel on my credit card for someone else? They have a valid U.S. passport but live in Ghana. I have been told that I may either have to be present when the board or that they have to purchase the ticket themselves. Is that true?

Comment: Is this person someone you know or someone you met on the internet? I am only asking because there’s a scam like that.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen I would put this a bit more strongly: there's a scam like that, and Ghana is one of the countries where such scammers frequently are (or claim to be) from.

Comment: @phoog I am Ghanaian so I typically try not to associate my country with crime. Actually in my original posting I wrote it exactly as you’re suggesting, then edited out the Ghana reference.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen it is certainly unfortunate that such activity can be associated with certain places and therefore bring disrepute (in the eyes of some) to people who have nothing to do with it. I therefore hesitated to post that comment. But since the best defense against such things is to promote awareness of them, it seemed best to mention that Ghana is one of the countries typically associated with these scams. Another seen here frequently is of course Russia. If the country had been New Zealand or Peru, would we have been so quick to mention the possibility?